# What motivates the use of 把 in Chinese?

Tags: grammar

I find sentences with 把 intriguing. I wonder why the Chinese language developed this usage. I, wrongly, made the assumption all sentences that use 把 like this can be simply rearranged.

I have this sentence from my text book:

它把灵魂塑造看得和学问同等重要。

So if I rearrange:

1. 它看灵魂塑造得和学问同等重要。 Not good I'm told.
2. 它看灵魂塑造和学问得同等重要。 Also not good.
3. 它看灵魂塑造和学问同等重要。 Also not good, not said this way.
4. 在它看来，灵魂塑造和学问同等重要。 Acceptable.

What motivates the use of 把 in Chinese？

Comment: These answers are similar.
It seems that all other answers more or less follow the earliest answer.

Comment: 它把灵魂塑造和学问看得同等重要，它把灵魂塑造看得和学问同等重要，它视灵魂塑造和学问同等重要。

Answer (score 3):

[把 ([介] 1)](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000000023) means 将.

> (1) 表示处理、处置的意思。(treating) 如：“把门关上”、“把脸洗净”。
>
> (2) 表示致使、导致的意思。(leading) 如：“把他惹恼了”、“把你气哭了”、“把我急疯了”。

把 or 将 is used in front of the object when we move the object to the front of the verb.

它把“灵魂塑造”看得和“学问”同等重要。

把...看得 = 视

它视“灵魂塑造”和“学问”同等重要。(The verb is in front of the objects.)

Comment: *"把 or 将 is used in front of the object when we move the object to the front of the verb."* -- It is more than that. Passive voice sentences  also move the object to the front of the verb. e.g. [灵魂塑造] [被它] 看得和 [学问] 同等重要; [把] and [将]  are [dispositive markers] that indicate the object is disposed in the manner of the verb.

Answer (score 2):

The character [把] or [將] directly placed before an [object] is called 'dispositive marker'. The role of a dispositive marker is to dispose the object.

"我殺了" (I killed) is a phrase with only subject and verb.

To make "我殺了" a complete sentence and explain " who killed whom" we can place the object after the verb  and write "我殺了[他]" (I killed him). It is a simple SVO sentence. The emphasis is on the subject and it's action.

Or you can insert [ dispositive marker+object] between the subject and the verb  and write " 我[把他]殺了" (I killed him) . The emphasis is on the object that is being disposed by the verb. ('**whom** was killed by me' is the more important information than 'I **killed** someone)

> In "送走他", [送] is the main verb, [走] is the resultive verb particle that indicate result of the action. The object [他] is placed directly after both.
>
> In "送他走", the object [他] is inserted between  the verb, [送] and its resultive particle [走]

Both phrases above focus on the verb

> In "把他送走" , the object is being disposed by the verb 送走

The focus in this sentence is the object being disposed by the subject in the method of the verb.

('**whom** is being sent away' is the more important information than 'the subject **send away** someone')

> In "打他一頓", [打] is the verb, [他] is the object,

This sentence focus on the verb 打.

> In "將他打一頓" the object,  [他] is disposed by the verb [打]

The focus in this sentence is the object being disposed by the subject in the method of the verb.

('**whom** is being beaten' is the more important information than 'the subject **beating** someone')

> You cannot use dispositive markers if the verb doesn't dispose the object

For example :

看他一眼 cannot be rephrased as  將他看一眼. - look at an object doesn't change the object's situation (should be 對他看一眼)

回答他 cannot be rephrased as  把他回答 - 回答 is not an action verb that can dispose an object ( should be 向他回答)

Comment: To clarify the use of 将, it can be used similarly to 把, but also to mean will.  The difference between the usage of 将　and 会, or 要 is that you’re implying that “his leaving” is a very significant decision.  The example I would like to give is: 他将离开这里。　送走他吧。　可惜他不会回来了。　That example should demonstrate the entirety of our responses.

Comment: 将 (will) is an auxiliary verb that always followed by a verb;  将(dispositive marker) always followed by a noun; in 他将离开这里, '他' is the subject

Answer (score 1):

“把”字句
S.+把+O.+V.+something

The 把-sentence indicates that an action is applied to somebody or something with emphasis that action will bring about a result. So here “something” is result.

她把鸡蛋吃了。
“她”is the Subject. “鸡蛋”is the Object. “吃”is the Verb. “了”is the result.

我把书包放在桌子上。
“我”is the Subject. “书包”is the Object. “放”is the Verb. “在桌子上”is the result.
他 把 我的自行车 借 走了。

If you want to know about the 把 sentences and 被 sentences， you can check this video http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/course/demo/%E6%8A%8A-sentence-and-%E8%A2%AB-sentence

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how correct this source is, but, it could possibly be because it makes the sentence easier to understand because we know the object sooner.

Especially, if one were to hear the object first, it gives them more time to decipher meaning, given the similarities in pronunciation.

As it stands, this is just accepted convention, and it is that way and we must follow it as such.